# PHPExcel: Make difference in 1.10 and 1.1 while extract

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have to extract experience of people in excel.
In some case experience is 10.1 year or 10.10 year (year.month).

While extracting, excel considers both the values as same.
how to handle this situation.

```
setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);
```

I have used this method along with object. But it is not working.

Comment: I'm unclear from your wuestion: do you mean that you writing that value to an excel file, or that you're reading the value from an Excel file?

Comment: writing value to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the style for the cell (or cell range) that you want using the built-in number format styles defined in `PHPEXcel_Style_NumberFormat.php`

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_00);
```

or use a manually defined style

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0.00');
```

If you wanted 3 decimal places instead, you'd use

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode('0.000');
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This is a correct way to handle this. But my problem is, numbers are not in decimal format like 00,01.. hence /FORMAT_NUMBER_00' or '0.00' not working there. So first i have to convert all nos in decimal format.

Comment: If the numbers are PHP numeric values (integer or float), then you don't need to do anything with them.... if it's a string or other PHP datatype, then you will need to convert it to a PHP integer or a float